# AWT dialog placement

Tags: java, linux, awt

I found the following [example code](http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1133/):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DialogExample {
    private static final int WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 250;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DialogExample();
    }

    public DialogExample() {
    final Frame f = new Frame();
    f.setTitle("Dialog Example");
    f.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    Panel p1 = new Panel() {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int left = DialogExample.WIDTH/2 - 45; // don't use WIDTH shadowed by Panel class
        int top = DialogExample.HEIGHT/2 - 20; // same as above
        g.drawString("Dialog Example", left, top);
        }
    };
    f.add("Center", p1);

    Panel p2 = new Panel();
    f.add("South", p2);

    Button b = new Button("Show Dialog");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        showDialog(f);
        }
    });
    p2.add(b);

    // close window on X
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){ 
        System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void showDialog(Frame owner) {
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(owner, "The Dialog", true); // true for modal
    d.add("Center", new Label("Hi, how are you?"));
    Button ok = new Button("OK");
    ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        d.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    d.add("South", ok);
    d.pack();

    // locate dialog to the center
    Dimension dd = d.getSize();
    Dimension pd = owner.getSize();
    Point pl = owner.getLocation();
    d.setLocation(
        pl.x + ((int) (pd.getWidth() - dd.getWidth()))/2,
        pl.y + ((int) (pd.getHeight() - dd.getHeight()))/2
    );
    d.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I'm confused by the part:

```
    Point pl = owner.getLocation();
    d.setLocation(
        pl.x + ((int) (pd.getWidth() - dd.getWidth()))/2,
        pl.y + ((int) (pd.getHeight() - dd.getHeight()))/2
    );
```

The documentation of [getLocation()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocation--) says this returns the *top-left corner of the component's bounds in the coordinate space of the component's parent*. As this panel does not have a parent, it looks like that means the coordinates relative to the top-left corner of my screen. Likewise, the [setLocation(x, y)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation-int-int-) documentation suggests these coordinates are in the parents' coordinate space too.

Of course the dialogs' parent is the panel, so it would appear to me that the above code is incorrect, and it should not add pl.x/pl.y to the coordinates when trying to center this dialog box. However, in fact the dialog *is* properly centered.

What am I missing here?

(the context of this question is that I'm maintaining a windowmanager, and dialogs from Java applications are often misplaced. That suggests my code is wrong, and I'm trying to find out why/where)

Comment: Find some more recent examples.  Seriously.  AWT was effectively replaced by Swing in Java 1.2. Finding the center point of a component of width and height has been unnecessary since `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` was introduced in 1.4.  But the best method for positioning frames is `setLocationByPlatform(true)` introduced in Java 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

`owner` is the parent of the dialog, not in the sense that the `Dialog` is the parent of the panels, but in the sense of one window owning another for the purpose of modality.

`Frame#getLocation` will return the location of the frame on the screen. `pd` is the `owner`'s (`Frame`s) size and `dd` is the dialogs size...

Of course, the whole thing could be achieved by using [`Dialog#setLocationRelativeTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29) and passing the reference of the `owner` to the method

Comment: Thanks for your reply - it does not quite answer my question yet though. Adding pl.x and pl.y to the coordinates passed to `d.setLocation` suggests that those coordinates relative to the screen. However, the documentation of `setLocation` suggests they're relative to the parent of the dialog, which is not the screen but the `owner` panel. That seems like a contradiction which I'm not sure how to resolve.

Comment: No, `pl.x` and `pl.y` will be relative to the dialog's content pane, which is likely to `0x0` as the panel will be placed in the "CENTER" position but occupy most of the space (excluding that space taken up by `p2`)

Comment: I just checked, and `pl.x` and `pl.y` are definitely relative to the top-left corner of the screen.

Comment: How do you know?  What are their values?

Comment: I checked with a debugger, they're the X/Y coordinates relative to the top-left of my monitor. Are you sure you're not confusing `pl` and `p1`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, `pl` is relative to the screen, which is what I said...`pl` is the `owner`'s (the `Frame`s) location on the screen, sorry, late